# Add two json object data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to add two JSON objects which have structure like this (It has more data and I ignore them in here):

```
{ "total_count":100 , "types":20 , { "a" : 5 , "b" : 6 }}

{"total_count" : 1 , { "a" : 2 } }
```

I want to add these objects in node.js in order to get following object:

```
 { "total_count":101 , "types":20 , { "a" : 7 , "b" : 6 }}
```

I use mongodb which has $inc function which add current json to existing one in db and reduce load and store load. I'm interested to find a method which handle this action in nodejs.What should I do ( I dont want to do it manually preferly. instead i like to use existing functions)?

Comment: I suggest writing some recursive function that adds all the values together. You'll need `for(var i in object)` syntax.

Comment: Well this isn't a duplicate IMO, since the OP does not just want to merge two objects blindly together, but wants to do some transformation on the data itself, so a tailored function would make much more sense. The OP should add more details, eg whether that is a generic request or for that specific problem with that specific object-properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this? your json structure is not quite correct, so i added x.

```
object1 = {"total_count":100 , "types":20 , "x": { "a" : 5 , "b" : 6 }};

object2 = {"total_count" : 1 , "x":{ "a" : 2 } };

object1.total_count += object2.total_count;
object1.x.a += object2.x.a;
```

Comment: This only partially answers the question: what if object 2 contains a value for b? You should make that more generic.

Comment: I presented only part of my object

Comment: Zim84, then just add b